# Many to many output on page

Tags: laravel

I have a many-to-many relationship in the same model, this is how it looks

```
 public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Article', 'articles' , 'article_id' , 'article_recommended_id');
    }

    public function article_recommendations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Article', 'article_recommendations' , 'article_id' , 'article_recommended_id');
    }
```

The question is how can I now display all this on the page php.blade

I am trying to do like this in a controller

```
$article_recommendations = Article::with(['article_recommendations' => function($query){
            $query->where('article_id', 1);
          }])->get();
```

And like this on the page itself

```
@foreach($article_recommendations as $article_recommend)
                    {{ $article_recommend->title }}
                @endforeach
```

But in the end I get all the articles that I have.

```
Schema::create('article_recommendations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_recommended_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('article_recommended_id')
                ->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('article_id')
                ->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: You don't have a where on your Article query.

Comment: @N69S anyway, I have only one recommended article attached to the first ID, but it displays all that are

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Could you please share your table structure so that I can answer better?

Comment: @NicoHaase all the recommended articles should be displayed, let's say I added 2 and 3 to the 1st id of the article, and I should display articles 2 and 3. But in the end, all that are

Comment: @JeyhunRashidov added to post

Comment: Now you want to only get recommended articles?

Comment: @JeyhunRashidov Yes that's right

Comment: @Kim2000 I shared the code where only recommended articles are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$article = Article::with('article_recommendations')->find(1);
```

and then in blade you may loop like this

```
@foreach($article->article_recommendations as $article_recommend)
                {{ $article_recommend->title }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only recommended articles, you need to organize your codes like this.

In Article model:

```
public function recommends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ArticleRecommend', 'recommends' , 'id' , 'article_id');
}
```

In my code I assume that you have a model named ArticleRecommend for your article_recommendations table.

In controller:

```
$article_recommendations = Article::whereHas('recommends')->get();
```

This code will only return you the recommended ones.

In blade:

```
@foreach($article_recommendations as $article_recommend)
    {{ $article_recommend->title }}
@endforeach
```